# Каким образом система идентифицирует ELF файл?

Tags: elf, linux

Каким образом система идентифицирует ELF файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые несколько байтов файла содержат предопределенную последовательность данных, однозначно трактуемых на машинах различных архитектур.
 1. "Магическое" число - константа определяющая ELF файл, как таковой.
 2. Класс машины - 32 бита или 64 бита.
 3. Вид кодирования - MSB или LSB.
 4. Версия формата 1, 2 и т.д.